# Form window not opening when I run the program because of a line in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, speech-recognition, state-machine, speech

I wrote this code in c# and the issue here is that when I run the program the form window will not show up because of this line: RecognitionResult result = recEngine.Recognize();
But when I comment it out the code runs I also commented out the switch cases because they use the e.result.. 
My main goal with this code is to change the Grammar whenever I say the keyword so do you have a better way solving this ?
Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace Lil_AI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        SpeechSynthesizer spekEngine = new SpeechSynthesizer();
         public enum ProcessState
        {
            on,
            command,
            off
        }

        public ProcessState current_state = ProcessState.off;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            btnDisable.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            spekEngine.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            //RecognitionResult result = recEngine.Recognize();

            Choices oncommands = new Choices();
            oncommands.Add(new string[] { "Please", "Bye" });
            GrammarBuilder ongBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            ongBuilder.Append(oncommands);
            Grammar ongrammar = new Grammar(ongBuilder);

            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "Turn on the lights", "Bye" });
            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gBuilder.Append(commands);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

            Choices offcommands = new Choices();
            offcommands.Add(new string[] { "Hello", "Bye" });
            GrammarBuilder offgBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            offgBuilder.Append(offcommands);
            Grammar offgrammar = new Grammar(offgBuilder);

           // recEngine.LoadGrammar(offgrammar);

            if (current_state == ProcessState.on)
            {
                recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(ongrammar);
                spekEngine.Speak("I'm waiting for your commands");
               /* switch (result.Text)
                {
                    case "Please":
                        current_state = ProcessState.command;
                        break;
                    case "Bye":
                        spekEngine.Speak("Bye, bye");
                        current_state = ProcessState.off;
                        break;
                }*/
            }
            if (current_state == ProcessState.command)
            {
                recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
              /*  switch (result.Text)
                {
                    case "Turn the lights on":
                        spekEngine.Speak("Of course");
                        break;
                    case "Bye":
                        spekEngine.Speak("Bye, bye");
                        current_state = ProcessState.off;
                        break;
                }*/
            }
            if (current_state == ProcessState.off)
            {
                recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(offgrammar);
              /*  switch (result.Text)
                {
                    case "Hello":
                        spekEngine.Speak("Hi there");
                        current_state = ProcessState.on;
                        break;
                }*/
            }
        }

        private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnDisable.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try handling exceptions and see what the error is

Comment: Don't use a blocking call like Recognize(), use RecognizeAsync() instead.  And subscribe the SpeechDetected event to know when it recognized something.

Comment: @Crowcoder There is no exception the program runs bur without the Form window... any other idea ?

Comment: I managed to get the exception by placing that line to the btnEnable_Click method: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot perform this operation while the recognizer is doing recognition.' This is obviously because I already started the RecognizeAsync() so Instead of forcing this I will find out another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Crowcoder, @Hans Passant thank you for the help. I managed to solve the issue by getting the grammars from a class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace AI_Graph
{  

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        public SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        public SpeechSynthesizer spekEngine = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        public class DemoCode
        {
            public Grammar on_Grammar()
            {
                Choices oncommands = new Choices();
                oncommands.Add(new string[] { "Please", "Bye" });
                GrammarBuilder ongBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
                ongBuilder.Append(oncommands);
                Grammar ongrammar = new Grammar(ongBuilder);
                ongrammar.Name = "Standby";

                return ongrammar;
            }

            public Grammar command_Grammar()
            {
               Choices commands = new Choices();
                commands.Add(new string[] { "Turn on the lights", "Bye" });
                GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
                gBuilder.Append(commands);
                Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
                grammar.Name = "ON";

                return grammar;
            }
            public Grammar off_Grammar()
            {
                Choices offcommands = new Choices();
                offcommands.Add(new string[] { "Hello", "Bye", "Good night", "Good morning" });
                GrammarBuilder offgBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
                offgBuilder.Append(offcommands);
                Grammar offgrammar = new Grammar(offgBuilder);
                offgrammar.Name = "OFF";

                return offgrammar;
            }

        }

        public DemoCode _Grammar = new DemoCode();

        public enum ProcessState
        {
            on,
            command,
            off
        }

        public ProcessState current_state = ProcessState.off;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
        here:
            do
            {
                if (current_state == ProcessState.on)
                {
                    recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(_Grammar.on_Grammar());
                    spekEngine.Speak("I'm waiting for your commands");
                    switch (e.Result.Text)
                    {
                        case "Please":
                            current_state = ProcessState.command;
                            richTextBox1.Text += e.Result.Grammar.Name;
                            break;
                        case "Bye":
                            spekEngine.Speak("Bye, bye");
                            current_state = ProcessState.off;
                            richTextBox1.Text += e.Result.Grammar.Name;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (current_state == ProcessState.command)
                {
                    recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(_Grammar.command_Grammar());
                    switch (e.Result.Text)
                    {
                        case "Turn the lights on":
                            spekEngine.Speak("Of course");
                            current_state = ProcessState.on;
                            richTextBox1.Text += e.Result.Grammar.Name;
                            break;
                        case "Bye":
                            spekEngine.Speak("Bye, bye");
                            current_state = ProcessState.off;
                            richTextBox1.Text += e.Result.Grammar.Name;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (current_state == ProcessState.off)
                {
                    recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(_Grammar.off_Grammar());
                    switch (e.Result.Text)
                    {
                        case "Hello":
                            spekEngine.Speak("Hi there");
                            current_state = ProcessState.on;
                            richTextBox1.Text += e.Result.Grammar.Name;
                            break;
                        case "Bye":
                            spekEngine.Speak("Bye, bye");
                            current_state = ProcessState.off;
                            richTextBox1.Text += e.Result.Grammar.Name;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } while (e.Result.Text != "Good night");

            if (e.Result.Text == "Good morning")
            {
                goto here;
            }
        }


        public void recEngine_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "  Speech detected at AudioPosition = " + e.AudioPosition;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(_Grammar.off_Grammar());
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            spekEngine.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
        }

        private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            btnDisable.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnDisable.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```